# How to save this rtmp flash video stream?

Tags: flash, security, rtmp, shockwave

My sister wanted me to save
http://esewingworkshop.com/video-lesson/overview-zipper-types flash video &
couple more for offline viewing purposes and asked me how to save it.

I immediately fired firebug in firefox but surprisingly the video source is not
in the requests.
http://hwcdn.net/m7n9i8d5/fms/videos/5_Standard_Zipper/B_Overview_of_Zipper_Types.flv.smil
is the last request that is being made. response being:

```
<smil>
<head>
<meta base="rtmp://fms006.lo1.hwcdn.net/m7n9i8d5/_definst_">
</head>
<body>
<video
src="fms/videos/5_Standard_Zipper/B_Overview_of_Zipper_Types?doppl=965d6485db1d06d2&dopsig=867922856d781b57521a1dd3f7c28c5b"></video>
</body>
</smil>
```

So, I its using `rtmp` streaming protocol. I tried to figure out the source of
this stream. I used "wireshark" and analysed the traffic and followed the TCP
stream

```
POST http://fms006.lo1.hwcdn.net/fcs/ident2 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-fcs
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: fms035.lo1.hwcdn.net
Content-Length: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 14
Server: FlashCom/3.5.5
Content-Type: text/plain

209.197.11.150POST http://209.197.11.219/open/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-fcs
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: 209.197.11.219
Content-Length: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 17
Server: FlashCom/3.5.5
Content-Type: application/x-fcs

Wubmcmj7Q1T-6Tic
POST http://209.197.11.219/idle/Wubmcmj7Q1T-6Tic/0 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-fcs
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: 209.197.11.219
Content-Length: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1
Server: FlashCom/3.5.5
Content-Type: application/x-fcs

POST http://209.197.11.219/send/Wubmcmj7Q1T-6Tic/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-fcs
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: 209.197.11.219
Content-Length: 1537
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 3074
Server: FlashCom/3.5.5
Content-Type: application/x-fcs
```

and these are HTTP POST requests made by shockwave flash player
(plugin-containter.exe) in order

```
http://fms006.lo1.hwcdn.net/fcs/ident2
http://209.197.11.150/open/1
http://209.197.11.150/idle/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/0
http://209.197.11.150/send/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/1
http://209.197.11.150/send/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/2
http://209.197.11.150/idle/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/3
http://209.197.11.150/send/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/4
http://209.197.11.150/send/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/5
http://209.197.11.150/idle/2BZmcmj6mhTWexFa/6
_this continues till /407..._
```

I don't get it. I'm little confused about how exactly this communication is
taking place? I'm unable to find the video source. As far as I understood, from
the SMIL request (browser made it) its getting the server address and then
shockwaveplayer is taking over the communication and responses to these HTTP
POST requests are the video in chunks.

But how & where is it identifying which video it wants? Where is RTMP? what is
the url? How can I download it?

Comment: If you are using Linux the video is stored in the `/tmp` folder as long as it is playing. It has the name like `Flash*` where the rest are random characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
rtmpdump -r rtmp://fms.484C.edgecastcdn.net/00484C/videos/5_Standard_Zipper \
-a 00484C/videos/5_Standard_Zipper -y B_Overview_of_Zipper_Types \
-W http://esewingworkshop.com/sites/default/libraries/mediaplayer-5/player_5.6.swf \
-o a.flv
RTMPDump v2.4-84-gdd57cd0
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
Starting download at: 0.000 kB
[...]
10780.451 kB / 241.50 sec (99.9%)
Download complete
```

Comment: I'm wondering how this can be the accepted answer. It doesn't explain anything about SMIL, nor RTMP... There is only a command with a bunch of constants like "00484C" that are not present in the original requests posted by the OP.

Comment: What I mean is that the answer is really narrow, and it answers only the first three lines of the question. You did a good job finding the stream and the parameters, but there's no way to understand how to reach the same result. I see no reasons for this question to stay on SO when it is so specific, and the accepted answer even _more_ specific.

Comment: @DavidCosta this question was upvoted 3 time which means 3 people believe the question should stay, and my answer was accepted which means one person believes the answer should stay. If you dont like them then use the flagging tools that are available.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this a programming related question, but here goes:

- **How/Where?**

  In the SMIL file, you see base and
  the video source. So full URL (probably protected):

  rtmp://fms006.lo1.hwcdn.net/m7n9i8d5/_definst_fms/videos/5_Standard_Zipper/B_Overview_of_Zipper_Types?doppl=965d6485db1d06d2&dopsig=867922856d781b57521a1dd3f7c28c5b
- **Where is RTMP?**

  Not sure what you are asking. The
  SMIL explicitly references the RTMP
  stream URL.
- **How to Download?**

  Best way would probably be to try using any number of [3rd party tools](http://www.google.com/search?q=capture+RTMP+stream) that are able to capture HTTP/RTMP streams via various mechanisms.

Not that you were asking (and not that this really was a programming related question), but  many sites will frown upon downloading their content without permission.